# python symmetric encryption to binary without timestamp

Tags: python, cryptography

I want to encrypt a .zip file using AES256 in Python. I am aware of the Python cryptography module, in particular the example given at:

https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/

However, I have needs that are a bit different:

- I want to output binary data (because I want a small encrypted file). How can I output in binary instead of armored ASCII?
- I do not want to have the plaintext timestamp. Any way to remove it?

If I cannot fix those points I will use another method. Any suggestions? I was considering issuing gpg commands through subprocess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at Fernet module, seems it encrypts and authenticates the data. Actually its safer than only encrypting (see [here](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html)). However, removing the timestamp, in the case of this module, doesn't make sense if you also want to authenticate.

Said that, seems you want to risky and only encrypt instead of encrypt and authenticate. You might follow the examples of the same module found at https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/. Just make sure this is what you really want.

As you're worried about size and want to use AES, you could try AES in CTR mode, which does not need padding, avoiding extra bytes at the end.

```
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

backend = default_backend()
key = os.urandom(32)
nonce = os.urandom(16)
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CTR(nonce), backend=backend)
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
ct = encryptor.update(b"a secret message") + encryptor.finalize()
print(ct)
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
print(decryptor.update(ct) + decryptor.finalize())
```

So, answering your questions:

- (1) The `update` method already returns a byte array.
- (2) This way there will be no plaintext data automatically appended to the ciphertext (but be aware of the security implications about not authenticating the data). However, you'll need to pass the IV anyway, what you would have to do in either case.